# Print first line in python stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with contents in the following format, the values are sperated by ";"

```
abc@test;value1;12345;value1.1
nmp@test;value2;98766;value2.1
plm@test;value1;12345;value1.1
```

I am working on a python script to print the value if line matches the input provided. In this, if the input value is "12345", the output will be as follows:-

```
abc@test;value1;12345;value1.1
plm@test;value1;12345;value1.1
```

what I need is only the first line from the output. Below is the code:-

```
with open (full_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if input_id in line:            
           print (line)
```

To split the value (columns), I found to use `line.split(";")[2]` in this case.

How to get only the 1st line/row from the output?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could solve this.
You can `break` from the loop as soon as you find the match.

```
result = None
with open (full_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if input_id in line:    
           result = line
           break
```

And then later, you can check if the `result` is `None` or not.

```
if result is None:
   print("No Match found")
else:
   print(f"Match found {result}")
```

OR

You can use generator expression:

```
with open(full_file,'r') as f:
    result = next(line for line in f if input_id in line, None)
```